# OnClickListener for CardView?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

How do I attach an `OnClickListener` to a `CardView`? I want every single card to have a different action when clicked.

I have a `RecyclerView` that has a custom adapter for displaying the cards. This is how it's [implemented](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should implement the `OnItemClickListener` in your `ViewHolder` class, and pass the current item to the `ViewHolder` instances on every `onBindViewHolder()`.

From [this post](http://andraskindler.com/blog/2014/migrating-to-recyclerview-from-listview/):

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View view;
    public Item currentItem;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                // item clicked
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.currentItem = items.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I defined the listener there.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer bit more....how I can know which cardView row is clicked.....If I use view,getId() it returns same id.

Comment: @Crawler you call `getAdapterPosition()` to get it's index in the list.

Comment: Are there any differences than doing it [this way](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html#recycleview_layouts)?

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I clicked the cards, nothing happened. But when I clicked just OUTSIDE the cards, the onClick event triggered. I'm assuming the CardView was absorbing the click event, preventing the above OnClick event from firing. EDIT: Ok, I got it to work. The problem was my CardView had it's 'clickable' property set to true. Once I removed that, the above code started handling OnClick events properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution for this problem:

1. First add reference to View view object in ViewHolder class

   ```
   public static class TouristViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       public ImageView img;
       public TextView name;
       public TextView description;
       public RatingBar rating;
       public View view;               // <----- here

       public TouristViewHolder(final View view) {
           super(view);
           this.view = view;            // <----- here
           // ... rest of code
      }
   }
   ```
2. Next, in method `onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position)`, I add a listener and set new `Intent`.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(TouristViewHolder touristViewHolder, final int position) {

   touristViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // <--- here
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.i("W4K","Click-"+position);
           context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class));  // <--- here
       }
   });
   ```

It works for me fine, hope it will help someone else.

Comment: Thisi is working perfectly but I think accepted answer is great because you are accessing instance method of `TouristViewHolder ` in overrides. Adding it when initialized in constructor is great **I think**.

Comment: In my case, I had to replace context with ````v.getContext()````

Answer (score 3):

1. you just add onClick Listener, which Item you want in onBindViewHolder. where easily accessing the value of that position. please check the below code.

   ```
    @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

       holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(html2text(results.get(position).getTitle().toString())));
       holder.description.setText(Html.fromHtml(html2text(results.get(position).getSummary().toString())));
       holder.url.setText(Html.fromHtml(html2text(results.get(position).getUrl().toString())));
       holder.url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("url",results.get(position).getUrl().toString());
              mContext. startActivity(intent);

           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Hello everybody this worked :

```
   cardView=findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```