# Android - Use CardView without RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm trying to create an app which shows a list of images with little description.When a card is clicked, it will take the user to another page where users can see the full description of image. I followed some tutorial and managed to create the main list with RecyclerView and CardView. Now, when user clicks on any card I want to show something like in the image but I don't know how to call it in the activity. What I further plan to do is if the text too long, I want to provide a 'Read More' link which will take user to another page which will show only text.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: The link gives a 404..

Comment: I don't understand your issue. `CardView` as just a `View` (like `TextView`, `ImageView`, ...). So you can put it in your layout, even if your are not using a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Let me try to explain it again:
Screen 1: List of images (fb feed kind of) with overlaying title and short description.
(Click on any image)
Screen 2: Show an individual image in as a Card with same format as above but full description.
(If description longer than x no. of words then add 'Read More' button and go to Screen 3)
Screen 3: This screen shows only text.
-------
Query: Will CardView show the image on screen 2 even if I don't use it with RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout something like that: [OnClickListener for CardView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081787/onclicklistener-for-cardview)

An Activity or link will be launched onClick.