# Onclick event is not triggered for Image button placed on Image View in the cardview

Tags: android, onclick, android-cardview, recycle

I have placed image button on top of image view which is inside a CardView. I want to trigger some action when user clicks on Image button. However first problem is when I get the image button using findViewById inside MainActivity, it returns null(may be because image view is inside item_row xml which shows row data in the card view).

The other problem is how to tackle such scenario where activity_main.xml is different which contains recycler view which has item_row.xml having image button on top of image view.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.innovation.myapp.jwelleryonrent.View;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.innovation.myapp.jwelleryonrent.R;
import com.innovation.myapp.jwelleryonrent.controller.jwelleryController;
import com.innovation.myapp.jwelleryonrent.model.adapter.CustomItemClickListner;
import com.innovation.myapp.jwelleryonrent.model.adapter.JwelleryAdapter;
import com.innovation.myapp.jwelleryonrent.model.pojo.JwelleryCollection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements jwelleryController.JwelleryCallbackListener {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private List<JwelleryCollection> mJwelleryList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JwelleryAdapter mJwelleryAdapter;
    private jwelleryController mController;
    private boolean isInFavourites = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        configToolbar();
        mController = new jwelleryController(MainActivity.this);
        configViews();
        ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "Item Added", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });




    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, container, false);
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItemToBag(v);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    private void addItemToBag(View v)
    {
        isInFavourites = true;
        ImageButton btnFaviourite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
        if(isInFavourites==true) {

            btnFaviourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
        }
        else
            btnFaviourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
        Snackbar.make(v, "Item added to Favourites", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }


    private void configToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }

    private void initializeAdapter()
    {

        mJwelleryAdapter = new JwelleryAdapter(mJwelleryList);

        mJwelleryAdapter.setOnItemClickListner(new CustomItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Item: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

//        mJwelleryAdapter = new JwelleryAdapter(mJwelleryList, new CustomItemClickListner() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Item: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            }
//        });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mJwelleryAdapter);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mController.startFetching();
            }
        });


    }


    private void configViews() {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        mController.startFetching();
        initializeAdapter();
//        mJwelleryAdapter= new JwelleryAdapter(mJwelleryList);

    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        @Override
        public void onFetchStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFetchProgress(JwelleryCollection jwellery) {
            mJwelleryAdapter.addJwellery(jwellery);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFetchProgress(List<JwelleryCollection> jwelleryList) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFetchComplete() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFetchFailure() {

        }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

item_row.xml which contains Image button (id=favIcon) on top of Image View. I want to trigger action on favIcon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flowerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favIcon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite_border"
        />



    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flowerImage"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flowerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flowerCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/flowerName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flowerPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/flowerCategory"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flowerInstruction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="New Text"
/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Code for ViewHolder class,

```
 public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mName, mCategory, mPrice, mInstructions;
    public ImageView mImage;


    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerImage);
        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerName);
        mCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerCategory);
        mPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerPrice);
        mInstructions = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flowerInstruction);

        ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItemToBag(v);
            }
        });


    }


    public Holder(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {
    // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
        super(itemView);

    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, why are you using quotes? Just write plain text. All you posted is the xml but you claim your `onClick` doesn't work because the `findViewById` is null. Post your actual code. The reason your `ImageButton` is null is most likely since you're calling it in your `Activity` but you're inflating the view in your adapter.

Comment: @Vimal can you share java code where you are setting onClickListener for imageButton?

Comment: Here is the Code for MainActivity.java for onCreate

 ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favIcon); // Here I am getting imgButton as null
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "Item Added", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();                
            }
        });

Comment: You need to provide me full code, so i can see if you are calling setOnClickListener maybe before you finding id for the same imageButton..

Comment: Added MainActivity.java and adapter code was in a earlier post which you resolved

Comment: And the error you are getting is nullPointerException for imageButton?

Comment: You can't initialize ImageButton in MainActivity.java. You need to initialize ImageButton in adapter and from there call setOnClickListener in your ViewHolder class.

Comment: Is this [a duplicate of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780567/onitemclick-not-working-for-card-view)? (Aside: please do not add "urgent" and other forms of begging here - the volunteer audience tends to think of it as quite rude).

Answer (score 0):

try it (rootView added):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, container, false);
    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addItemToBag(v);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: When onCreateView is tirggered? because right now it's not triggering when I click on Image Button.
The other way I did is take the entire code of onCreateView and placed inside ViewHolder constructor, image button click is triggered but when I scroll the list , the addItemToBag function code is executed though I have not clicked on Image button of any other card..

Comment: Do you suggest solution to above comments?

Comment: I can't see your holder code,plz send it.
this is the right to do it in your holder constructor.

Comment: Code for holder class is added

Comment: would you like to suggest any solution?

Comment: I see your holder code and I don't know why it doesn't work,maybe the problem is elsewhere.
I have a code in your context that work nice, wanna send you?