# Android Cardview Menu Item Click to opens Different Activity

Tags: java, android

I am having a hard time figuring this one out. I am creating an Android app where the user (once logged in) sees an activity with a cardview list inside a recycler view.

I want the user to be able to click item on a card and go to a different activity. If you click menu item on card 1 you must go to the activity for game 1. If you click menu item on card 2 you must go to the activity for game 2. Etc...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please add some code snippets or an explanation of things you have already tried and be more specific about what you need.

Comment: Initially you will require a login activity to verify credentials..after that you need to add a recycler view and cardview inside it..After that you can set onclicklistner to the card and handle activity switching ..here are the links:1 For the cardview part https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/ ..To add onclicklistner refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081787/onclicklistener-for-cardview

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/                                                                                                         here is the code and each cardview have one menu item( bottom right on every cardview) so i want each cardview menu item click open diff activity [ If you click on card 1menu  you must go to the activity for game 1. If you click on card 2 menu you must go to the activity for game 2. ]                             cardview item name is "About"

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter's ViewHolder class add following:

```
 public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             // Start your activity


        });
    }
```

Create switch case to open different activities and then get recycler view position on the basis of that and provide different URL for each cards.